# Python error while running opencv (Blinking detection)

Tags: python, opencv

I use visual studio 2019,(Python3.6 / 64bit)

It is a code that detects blinking and mouth opening using opencv and dlib.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\이시우\source\repos\planners facedetect\test1.py", line 132, in <module>
    mouths = get_mouth_pen_ratio( mouth_points, landmarks)
NameError: name 'landmarks' is not defined
[ WARN:0] global D:\bld\libopencv_1632857399304\work\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (438) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
```

The above error appears when turning the code.

At first, it worked well, but suddenly this error occurred. What's the problem?

```
 for face in faces:
        landmarks = predictor(gray, face)
```

I looked for the problem while executing the sentences one by one, and I found that above code skipped the sentence in the for statement.

Below is the full text of the code I wrote.

In while statement, we measured the ratio of eyes when we opened and closed through the if, elif statement, and wrote to detect blinking through the intermediate value.

```
import cv2
import dlib
from math import hypot
import timeit
import winsound as sd

def beepsound():
    fr = 2000    
    du = 1000    
    sd.Beep(fr, du)


detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
predictor = dlib.shape_predictor("./shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat")

font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

mouth_points = [48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67]
r_eye_points = [42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47]
l_eye_points = [36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41]

count_mouth_open = 0

def midpoint(p1, p2):
    return int((p1.x + p2.x)/2), int((p1.y + p2.y)/2)


def get_mouth_pen_ratio(mouth_points, facial_landmarks):
   
    left_point = (facial_landmarks.part( mouth_points[12]).x, facial_landmarks.part(mouth_points[12]).y)
    right_point = (facial_landmarks.part( mouth_points[16]).x, facial_landmarks.part(mouth_points[16]).y)
    center_top = midpoint(facial_landmarks.part( mouth_points[13]), facial_landmarks.part(mouth_points[14]))
    center_bottom = midpoint(facial_landmarks.part( mouth_points[19]), facial_landmarks.part(mouth_points[18]))

    
    hor_line = cv2.line(image, left_point, right_point, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    ver_line = cv2.line(image, center_top, center_bottom, (0, 255, 0), 2)
   
    hor_line_lenght = hypot( (left_point[0] - right_point[0]), (left_point[1] - right_point[1]))
    ver_line_lenght = hypot( (center_top[0] - center_bottom[0]), (center_top[1] - center_bottom[1]))

    
    if ver_line_lenght != 0:
        ratio = hor_line_lenght / ver_line_lenght
    else:
        ratio = 60
    
    return ratio



def get_blinking_ratio(eye_points, facial_landmarks):
    
    left_point = (facial_landmarks.part( eye_points[0]).x, facial_landmarks.part(eye_points[0]).y)
    right_point = (facial_landmarks.part( eye_points[3]).x, facial_landmarks.part(eye_points[3]).y)
    center_top = midpoint(facial_landmarks.part( eye_points[1]), facial_landmarks.part(eye_points[2]))
    center_bottom = midpoint(facial_landmarks.part( eye_points[5]), facial_landmarks.part(eye_points[4]))

    hor_line = cv2.line(image, left_point, right_point, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    ver_line = cv2.line(image, center_top, center_bottom, (0, 255, 0), 2)

    hor_line_lenght = hypot( (left_point[0] - right_point[0]), (left_point[1] - right_point[1]))
    ver_line_lenght = hypot( (center_top[0] - center_bottom[0]), (center_top[1] - center_bottom[1]))

    ratio = ver_line_lenght / hor_line_lenght
    
    return ratio



capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)


capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)
capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480)


frame = 0
sum =0
open_average_ear = 0
close_average_ear = 0
step_count = 0
sleep_frame = 0


while True :
    
    if step_count == 0: 
        print("3초간 평소 눈의 크기를 측정합니다\n")
        while True:
            ready = input("편안하게 눈을 떠주시고 준비가 되셨으면 r을 입력해주세요: ")
            if ready == 'r':
                step_count += 1
                break
            else:
                print("잘못된 입력 값입니다. 다시 입력해주세요\n")
    elif step_count == 2:
        print("3초간 감은 눈의 크기를 측정합니다\n")
        print("부저소리가 날때까지 눈을 편안하게 감아주세요\n")
        while True:
            ready = input("준비가 되셨으면 r을 입력해주세요: ")
            if ready == 'r':
                step_count += 1
                break
            else:
                print("잘못된 입력 값입니다. 다시 입력해주세요\n")
    elif step_count == 4:
        print("s를 입력하면 졸음 인식 시스템이 시작됩니다.")
        while True:
            ready = input("준비가 되셨으면 s을 입력해주세요: ")
            if ready == 's':
                break
            else:
                print("잘못된 입력 값입니다. 다시 입력해주세요\n")
        print("q를 누르면 시스템이 종료됩니다.")
        step_count += 1

    _, image = capture.read()

    # convert frame to gray
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
                                                    
    faces = detector(gray)                         

    for face in faces:
        landmarks = predictor(gray, face)          
        
    mouths = get_mouth_pen_ratio( mouth_points, landmarks)
    if mouths <= 5.0: 
        count_mouth_open += 1

    left_eye_ratio = get_blinking_ratio( l_eye_points, landmarks)
    right_eye_ratio = get_blinking_ratio( r_eye_points, landmarks)

    blinking_ratio = (left_eye_ratio + right_eye_ratio) / 2

    
    if frame < 100: 
        frame = frame + 1
        sum = sum + blinking_ratio
    elif frame == 100:
        open_average_ear = sum / frame 
        print("ear = %f" %open_average_ear)
        sum = 0
        step_count += 1
        frame +=1 
        continue
    elif frame > 100 and frame < 200: 
        frame = frame + 1
        sum = sum + blinking_ratio
    elif frame == 200:
        close_average_ear = sum / (frame-100) 
        print("ear = %f" %close_average_ear)
        step_count += 1
        frame += 1 
        beepsound() 
        continue

    
    if close_average_ear != 0: 
        cv2.putText(image, "Mouth open: " + str(count_mouth_open), (50, 50), font, 2, (255, 0, 0))
        print("Mouth open: " + str(count_mouth_open)) 

        if blinking_ratio <= (open_average_ear + close_average_ear)/2:  
            cv2.putText(image, "blinking", (50, 50), font, 2, (255, 0, 0))
            print("blink")
            sleep_frame += 1

    
    if sleep_frame > 2: 
        frame += 1
        if frame - 201 == 15:
            if sleep_frame > 13: 
                print("졸음운전 판단")
                beepsound()
                sleep_frame = 0
                frame = 201
                pass 
            else:
                sleep_frame = 0 
                frame = 201 
                 

    
    cv2.imshow("Frame", image)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    
    if key == ord("q"): 
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagine, what happens if the faces detector does not find anything:

```
faces = detector(gray)

for face in faces:
    landmarks = predictor(gray, face)

mouths = get_mouth_pen_ratio( mouth_points, landmarks)
```

Then your `landmarks` is indeed not defined here, therefore there is the error.

Now, it really depends on what you want to do when no faces are detected. For example skip to the next frame? Something like this?

```
faces = detector(gray)
if not faces:
    continue

for face in faces:
    landmarks = predictor(gray, face)

if not landmarks:
    continue

mouths = get_mouth_pen_ratio( mouth_points, landmarks)
```

Also I believe the logic is wrong in your code. If you have more faces, you only keep the landmarks from the last one, detecting the mouths only on the last face. How about:

```
faces = detector(gray)
for face in faces:
    landmarks = predictor(gray, face)
    if landmarks:
        mouths = get_mouth_pen_ratio( mouth_points, landmarks)
        # do something with mouths...
```